# C program keeps listing address and not values with no pointers present

Tags: c

I am creating a code to compare todays date to an array of dates in structures. Every time i try to print the dates, I get back the address and not the actual value itself.

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct date {
    int month[2];
    int day[2];
    int year[4];
};

int cmpDate(struct date date1, struct date date2)
{
if (date1.year > date2.year)
        return 1;
    if (date1.year < date2.year)
        return -1;
    if (date1.year == date2.year)
    {
        if (date1.month > date2.month)
            return 1;
        if (date1.month < date2.month)
            return -1;
        if (date1.month == date2.month)
        {
            if (date1.day > date2.day)
                return 1;
            if (date1.day < date2.day)
                return -1;
            if (date1.day == date2.day)
                return 0;
        }
    }
};

struct date list[10] = { { 12, 3, 2016 },
{ 12 , 8 ,2012 },
{ 9, 3, 2016 },
{ 11, 7, 2012 },
{ 11, 7, 2020 },
{ 11, 7, 2016 },
{ 8, 1, 2017 },
{ 12, 29, 2017 },
{ 10, 1, 2018 } };

int main(void)
{
    struct date today;
    int i;
    int j = 0;

    printf("Enter todays date in the following format: MM DD YYYY:\n");
    scanf_s("%d %d %d", today.month, today.day, today.year);
    printf("\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%d %d %d\n", list[i].month, list[i].day, list[i].year);
        printf("%d %d %d\n", today.month, today.day, today.year);
        printf("%d\n", j);
    }

}
```

the code compiles fine, but here is what i get when i debug:

```
Enter todays date in the following format: MM DD YYYY:
04 25 2017

14979072 14979080 14979088
9435988 9435996 9436004
0
14979104 14979112 14979120
9435988 9435996 9436004
0
14979136 14979144 14979152
9435988 9435996 9436004
0
14979168 14979176 14979184
9435988 9435996 9436004
0
14979200 14979208 14979216
9435988 9435996 9436004
0
14979232 14979240 14979248
9435988 9435996 9436004
0
14979264 14979272 14979280
9435988 9435996 9436004
0
14979296 14979304 14979312
9435988 9435996 9436004
0
14979328 14979336 14979344
9435988 9435996 9436004
0
14979360 14979368 14979376
9435988 9435996 9436004
0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

J is just a place holder for where I'm going to call the function cmpDate, so it's not really important right now. Can anyone help me print the value, and not the address?

Thank you.

Comment: `int month[2];
    int day[2];
    int year[4];` --> `int month;
    int day;
    int year;` and `scanf_s("%d %d %d", today.month, today.day, today.year);` --> `scanf_s("%d %d %d", &today.month, &today.day, &today.year);`

Comment: if your compiler didn't warn you about the mismatch of parameters to `printf`'s format string, you either need to crank up your compiler warnings or get a different toolchain, and even then, still crank them up. [See example warnings/errors here](https://pastebin.com/5G8iNQus).

Answer (score 0):

Because the members of the structure are arrays, referring to their name (e.g. `list[i].day` actually results in a pointer to the array. You would need to reference each element in the array separately in the `printf` function to print all the digits.

Comment: It results in a pointer to the array's initial element, not to the entire array. It's the same memory address, but it has a different type. In any case, passing a pointer value to `printf` with a `%d` format has undefined behavior (printing a decimal form of the address is the most likely result).

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure is defined incorrectly.

I think you're assuming that

```
int year[4];
```

defines `year` as a 4-digit integer. It doesn't. Rather, it defines it as an array of 4 `int` values.

Trying to treat an `int[4]` object as an `int` object is causing problems that would take a while to describe. It has to do with the relationship between arrays and pointers. See section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/) for the details. But in the meantime, rather than worrying about why you're getting things that look like addresses, just fix the code.

```
int year;
```

An `int` is guaranteed to be able to hold values up to *at least* 65535, and on most systems you're likely to use up to about 2 billion, so you don't need to do anything special to be able to represent years. (If you did, you could use type `long` rather than `int`, with corresponding adjustments to the code to deal with the different type, but that's not necessary here.)